# Questions about several developers working on a Python Package

Tags: python, software-design, software-distribution

If multiple developers were to develop a python package, how should we deal with these problems:

(1) What is the best practice to make all developers use the same dev environment?

(2) On dev end, do all of us need to use .../site-package/mypackage as our dev path (map code from version control to there and develop code there) as if things were installed to that path using pip?

Comment: use poetry if by dev environment you mean same pyversions and package versions.... use docker or other containers if you mean identical systems(likely in combination with  poetry)

Comment: you can simply use a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate the list of packages. Others can then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to use the same packages. You can additionally add versions to the packages in `requirements.txt` to enforce same versions.

Comment: Use a common style guide for writing code and a popular code formatter. Also use virtual environment.

Comment: +1 for poetry. Also recommend precommit (with black and flake8) and vscode. Eg https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/development/guide/environment.html

Answer (score 1):

Suggest use virtual environment (venv) to control python version and package version. Under venv, `pip freeze > requirements.txt` can only output what your project needs. Other developers just need to create a new one in their project folder and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. It can avoid version conflicts of different projects.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: During dev process if it's required to add, remove or change versions of dependencies, does the first developer need to re-generate requirements.txt for multiple times and the second developer needs to re-run pip install -r requirements.txt for multiple times to match dependencies?

Comment: Yes, in my experience, it cannot be avoided.

Comment: Or you can also use docker or compressed venv folder to share for other developers to use.

Comment: So both requirements.txt and setup.py need to be regularly maintained which is error-prone and time-consuming. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I think you may not change requirements.txt every time, just only update it when using a new package. You can also use CI tools to verify if changes are needed. For example, add a test script to confirm that it is valid every time it is submitted.